# Find distinct of a value from a list of value

Tags: sql-server

Below is like my dataset -

[image]

I want to pull `Jil_Equipment_ID` which contains only 1. If it contains anything apart from 1 in a group, it should be neglected.

So the result will be `90025`, `6106396`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it - since the value requested is 1, the sum and count should be the same:

```
SELECT Jil_Equipment_ID, 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Jil_Equipment_ID 
HAVING SUM(ISNULL(Req_Rule_Id, 1)) = COUNT(ISNULL(Req_Rule_Id, 1))
```

Comment: This is working for me. Just checking if there are any scenarios failing. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a subquery, basically make a subquery containing all Jil_Equipment_Id that contain data other than NULL or 1, then exclude these;

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (Jil_Equipment_Id int, Req_Rule_id int)
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES
(90025,NULL)
,(90025,1)
,(100295,NULL)
,(100295,2)
,(100295,3)
,(3265569,NULL)
,(3265569,1)
,(3265569,2)
,(3265569,9)
,(4091637,NULL)
,(4091637,1)
,(4091637,3)
,(6106396,NULL)
,(6106396,1)
,(6106396,1)
,(6106396,1)
```

Actual Query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
a.Jil_Equipment_Id
FROM #TestData a
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT DISTINCT 
           Jil_Equipment_Id
           FROM #TestData
           WHERE Req_Rule_id <> 1
            AND Req_Rule_id IS NOT NULL
          ) b 
ON a.Jil_Equipment_Id = b.Jil_Equipment_Id
WHERE b.Jil_Equipment_Id IS NULL
```

Results;

```
Jil_Equipment_Id
90025
6106396
```

Depending upon the size of your data, you may want to look into the NOT EXISTS operator. I've kept it like this as it will be more readable to the widest range of users.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an (almost) literal translation of your requirement to SQL:

```
SELECT Jil_Equipment_ID      /* I want to pull Jil_Equipment_ID */
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE Req_Rule_ID = 1       /* which contains only 1. */
   AND NOT EXISTS (     
       SELECT 1
         FROM MyTable AS t2              /* If it contains anything */
        WHERE MyTable.Jil_Equipment_ID   /* apart from 1 in a group, */
                 = t2.Jil_Equipment_ID   /* it should be neglected. */
          AND Req_Rule_ID <> 1
       )
```

It's not optimized for performance, but it's easy to understand, and, thus, to verify its correctness.

Comment: Seems the most appropriate answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Both the min and max must be the same value if there is only a single distinct value per group

```
SELECT Jil_Equipment_ID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Jil_Equipment_ID 
HAVING MAX(Req_Rule_Id) = 1 
AND MIN(Req_Rule_Id) = 1
```

Another way is to include a count distinct along with min or max.

```
SELECT Jil_Equipment_ID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Jil_Equipment_ID 
HAVING MAX(Req_Rule_Id) = 1 
AND COUNT (DISTINCT Req_Rule_Id) = 1
```